# iphone locking all functionality except calling

Tags: iphone, service, system

I am thinking of making an app for my younger brother's iphone, through which i could lock all functionality of iPhone except making and receiving calls for the time he is doing homework. Will apple allow me? if "yes" then how?

Comment: how about taking iPhone from him when he is doing homework?

Comment: Voting to close. Not really a programming specific question. Having said that, the answer to your question is no.

Comment: Better dont give iphone to him when he is doing home work

Comment: @sosborn: Why is it not a programming question? If he asked "how to program this" (given that has apple sdk, a developer license, etc) would it be any better?

Comment: @zespri "how to program this" would not be a better question. A better question would be "I tried this <insert code> and I received <insert result> but I expected <insert expected result>." People have different thoughts on what makes a good question though, which is why four other people would have to agree with me to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are no public APIs to do what you're asking. If you managed to use Apple's private APIs to do this (which would take an extremely large amount of effort), Apple would reject your app from the app store. That said, if you're just looking to install the app on his phone, you can do that with a $99 developer license and Xcode.